# # not followed by macro parameter

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following code:

```c
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15
#define PRINT_CELL(x) \
    printf("|%" #MAX_NAME_LEN "s|", #x);
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
main.c:9:21: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
    9 | #define PRINT_CELL(x) \
      |                     ^
```

I'm not quite sure what I did wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: §6.10.3.2 p1: *"Each # preprocessing token in the replacement list for a function-like macro shall be followed by a parameter as the next preprocessing token in the replacement list."*

Comment: In other words, you can only use it with arguments to that macro, not with other arbitrary names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#MAX_NAME_LEN` is illegal because `MAX_NAME_LEN` is not an identifier in the replacement list of the `PRINT_CELL(x)` [macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace). Use the following, instead:

```
#define PRINT_CELL(x) printf("|%*s|", MAX_NAME_LEN, #x);
```

Comment: Don't use the `;` or you'll incurr in errors most of the time.

Comment: @LuisColorado That's a good point, and there are a number of alternatives discussed under [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros) for example. That said, in this case the `;` was in OP's code and I left it there because it's not related to the main point of the question.

Comment: it's generally more C style to take it off, so if you need it you can allways say `PRINT_CELL(ARGUMENT);` but what if you have `if (a) PRINT_CELL(ARGUMENT); else b();` will generate a syntax error, as the `if` statement will end with the second `;` token.  That's the same problem as with the idiom `#define PRINT_CELL(arg) do{ printf(bla bla); } while (0)`  (without the last semicolon)

Answer (score 2):

The `#x` is fine because `x` is a macro *argument*.

But, `#MAX_NAME_LEN` is *not* fine because `MAX_NAME_LEN` is *not* a macro *argument*

You can fix this with an extra "helper" macro:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15

#define STRINGIFY(s) \
    #s

#define PRINT_CELL(x) \
    printf("|%" STRINGIFY(MAX_NAME_LEN) "s|", #x);
```

---

That solves the complaint from `cpp`, but the result compiles with an error because the output produces a complaint about the format string for `printf`:

```
int
main(void)
{
 printf("|%" "MAX_NAME_LEN" "s|" "hello");
 return 0;
}
```

---

To solve that, change: `%` to `%%`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15

#define STRINGIFY(s) \
    #s

#define PRINT_CELL(x) \
    printf("|%%" STRINGIFY(MAX_NAME_LEN) "s|" #x "\n");

int
main(void)
{

    PRINT_CELL(hello)

    return 0;
}
```

But, when we *run* that version, the output of program is:

```
|%MAX_NAME_LENs|hello
```

---

What I suspect you're trying to do can be accomplished better using the `*` modifier of `%s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15

#define STRINGIFY(s) \
    #s

#define PRINT_CELL(x) \
    printf("|%*s\n",MAX_NAME_LEN,#x);

int
main(void)
{

    PRINT_CELL(hello)

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
|          hello
```